# Enabling window decorations made me disable unity plugin. No borders

Tags: unity, compiz

So I started messing around with Compiz a bit

I enabled window decorations but that made me disable unity plugin

So no launcher and no task bar or whatever it's called in Linux I accidentaly minimised the Compiz Settings and POOF it's gone I opened the monitor settings to end compiz's process now am stuck with no borders at all! so I booted into Live mode just to ask here :z do I need a fresh install or is there a solution?

Comment: have you tried to purge unity and reinstall ubuntu-desktop? with like, `sudo apt-get purge unity && sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` There might be a better command bot this does the job at least. It might be a good idea to purge compiz as well, just to get rid of it. Have you tried to create a new user? that might work as well..

Comment: That's the point there is NO terminal i cant open it even with ctrl+alt+t :$

Comment: can you open in fail safe mode, like when you boot you can select different kernels and fail safe?

Comment: Open a Virtual Console. Ctrl-Alt-F1 to open it, Ctrl-Alt-F7 to go back to your graphic display.

Comment: " do I need a fresh install " this is hardly ever needed. Though sometimes it is the quickest method :)

Answer (score 6):

Open a Virtual Console. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open it.

```
rm ~/.gconf ~/.gconfd ~/.metacity ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/.config/dconf -rf
```

And then reboot. It will remove all the settings and start Ubuntu in vanilla state.

Comment: Nope , nothing most of them are not there and they cannot be removed except a  compiz folder was found and it said cant remove too. =/

Comment: did you try removing them with root user?
I guess .gconf and .config are enough.

Comment: still , nothing

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

All the solutions above did not work for me. What did, instead, is this

```
rm -rf ~/.config/gtk-3.0
```

after having removed what @ajit said

```
rm  -rf ~/.gconf ~/.gconfd ~/.metacity ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/.config/dconf
```

## How to fix it

In conclusion, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, log in to your account

```
sudo service lightdm stop
rm  -rf ~/.gconf ~/.gconfd ~/.metacity ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/.config/dconf ~/.config/gtk-3.0
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Answer (score -1):

Install unity-tweak-tool:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Then run as normal user:

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```