# Something strange has happened to my Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.04

This happened just a few days ago and I've been making do but it has really started to bother me.

When I click <kbd>F12</kbd> on startup and select my Ubuntu it loads fine and I sign in but once I'm signed in for some reason I cannot see any toolbars, for instance the 'tray' with the time and battery left, etc nor can I see the slide bar on the right that has your favorites, nor can I resize any windows?

I can navigate through things using the terminal because I know how to but I can't even close windows, and they all stack up on the top left corner of the screen and since I cannot close or move these windows I am having a hard time.

Maybe I pressed some shortcut to like, lock my windows? or something any help would be great

Comment: The Utopic Unicorn (14.10) has already reached its end of life, thefore it's considered off-topic here. Please consider upgrading to a current version(latest LTS: 14.04, latest regular release: 15.10).

Comment: it seems like it is but i unfortunately cannot ask for help as i do not have 50 reputation. `compiz-core:i386` is what is installed when i run the command in the answer, but i get an error when i run 'DISPLAY=:0 ccsm' all i get is `-bash: ccsm: command not found`

Comment: @SenjuXo EOL releases get no support here is what Eduardo is saying.  14.10 is long dead so to get continues support you need to upgrade

Comment: I've tried to, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` if i recall? or a command along those lines never changes it from 14.10

Answer (score 0):

You could check out some of these:

[Enabling window decorations made me disable unity plugin. No borders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465377/enabling-window-decorations-made-me-disable-unity-plugin-no-borders)

[How to set borders around windows in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454263/how-to-set-borders-around-windows-in-14-04)

[Unity missing? Can't see top or side panels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204428/unity-missing-cant-see-top-or-side-panels)

You can also look around here on the site for more questions (and solutions) on how to fix the window decorations or how to reset unity all together.

Good luck!